# Error: Received unknown parameter: source

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

I'm making a react-redux app with firetore as database. Now, I wanted to use firebase cloud functions for handling stripe payments.

Here is the cloud function "createSubscription":

```
exports.createSubscription = functions.database
  .ref("/teachers/{userId}/pro-membership/token")
  .onWrite((event, context) => {
    const tokenId = event.after.val();
    const userId = context.params.userId;

    if (!tokenId) throw new Error("Token Missing");

    return admin
      .database()
      .ref(`teachers/${userId}`)
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => snapshot.val())
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user);

        return stripe.subscriptions.create({
          customer: user.customerId,
            source: tokenId,                 **// Here is the error occuring**
          items: [
            {
              plan: "pro-membership"
            }
          ]
        });
      })
      .then(sub => {
        admin
          .database()
          .ref(`teachers/${userId}/pro-membership`)
          .update({
            status: "active"
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("ERRor", err);
      });
  });
```

Below is the error information from cloud function's logs:

[image: Below is the error information from cloud function's logs]

Comment: This sounds like some Stripe error not google cloud related.

Comment: I don't know why, but I have edited it about 5 times, and I change it to "firebase-cloud-functions", but it won't change from "google-cloud-functions". So, I am just removing this tag.

Comment: `source` is not a valid parameter on a `stripe.subscriptions.create` request, see  https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create --- try updating the customer first, adding the token (https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update), *then* create a subscription.

Comment: @duck It's working man. Thank you! You can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` is not a valid parameter on a `stripe.subscriptions.create` request, see https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create

Try updating the customer first, adding the token, https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update, then create a subscription!